# Separation of variables won't work

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all solutions on $\mathbb{R}$ of the differential equation $y'=3|y|^{2/3}.$

Why wouldn't separation of variables method work for this differential equation? Why does the initial condition have to be nonzero?

Comment: While the separation of variables method is applicable, one does not find all solutions this way. One may construct other solutions by cutting one solution at a point with $y(x)=0$ and moving the halves to the side, away from each other, inserting a segment where $y=0$.

Comment: @LutzL why would that be the case here? If I was given a different problem how would I know if the separation of variables applies to that problem?

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand your statement "*the separation of variables method will only work if the initial condition is nonzero*".

I have problem with the absolute value so I shall only help you solving $$y'=3 y^{2/3}$$ You can separate the variables and integrate both sides. This leads to $$y^{1/3}=x+c$$ and then $$y=(x+c)^3$$ I hope and wish this could help continuing with your problem.

Comment: This does not solve the equation--which is a well-known example where Cauchy-Lipschitz conditions fail and the solutions are not unique, as explained in a comment.